# match implode data vs another implode

Tags: php, mysql, match, implode

I have data from two different tables where the data have been implode after being selected from Checkboxes and they are divided by a ','. After i selected them from the database the two varibles could look like this.

```
$firstvar = Red, Blue, Green, Yellow

$secondvar = Green, Purple, White
```

So i want to know how i can check, if there is a match, when there is at least one of the colors that match in the two variables.

i've been trying with:

```
if (strpos($firstvar , $firstvar ) !== false) {
    echo 'There is a match';
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: array_intersect per chance? - odd because your example (almost) exactly matches that in the manual !!?!?!

Comment: To @Strawberry point do this before you implode them...

Comment: better option array_intersect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fetching the result from the database, explode these two variables:

Just like this:

```
$firstvar = explode(",",$firstvar);
$secondvar = explode(",",$secondvar );
```

Now, use this function:

```
$match = array_intersect($firstvar,$secondvar);
```

and now, implode the resulted output:

```
$result = implode(",",$match);
echo $result;
```

Hope, this may be useful to you.

Comment: This seemed like the way to go but i'm having weird problems with the code. Let's take an example with music genres:

$var = 'Pop, Blues';vartwo = 'Jazz, Rock, Pop';
$genreone = explode(",",$var);   
$genretwo = explode(",",$vartwo);

$result = array_intersect($genreone, $genretwo);
if(!empty($result)){
    echo 'Works';
}else{
   echo 'Does not work';
}
This make it say there is no match, but there are clearly one with the genre Pop.

Comment: It is not working, because in $vartwo, there is a extra space in 'Pop' after comma, please remove extra space or during exploding provide extra space with comma, just like this-> $genreone = explode(", ",$var);

Comment: In simple saying, the way you have imploded the data(array to string) before saving in database, just explode the data(string to array) into same way after retrieving from database. For example: If you have provided extra space after comma during implode brfore saving into database, so during explode also provide a extra space after comma after retrieving from database, otherwise an extra space will be inserted into array values.